# Basic SQL Help - Syntax error in Query Expression

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error

I am beginning to learn SQL and I have made a basic .mdb table. I am trying to have a page where the user selects a book category and when they click on it, the next page will have the book content & author within the book category they chose. I currently only have 1 book and author listed per category to keep it simple for now.

Initially the server was selecting the very first book within the database for all book category selections, so I tried to incorporate the user chosen category, but now I am getting an error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message Source: Microsoft Office Access Database Engine Description: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'author='.' in E:\server\Database\moredetails2.php Stack trace: #0 E:\server\Database\moredetails2.php(20): com->Execute('SELECT Books, C...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\server\Database\moredetails2.php on line 20"

My code for the page is:

```
<?php
$authorid=filter_input(INPUT_GET, "author");

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
//$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 

Source=../Database/poebase.mdb";
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 

Source=../Database/poebase.mdb";
//creates the connection object and define the connection string

$conn->Open($connString);

$selectCommand="SELECT Books, Author, Content FROM Authors WHERE author=$authorid;";

$rs = $conn->Execute($selectCommand);
//opens a recordset from the connection object
if (!$rs->EOF){
$BookName=$rs->Fields("Books");
$AuthorName=$rs->Fields("Author");
$BookContent=$rs->Fields("Content");
}

print "Book: $BookName<br>";
print "Author: $AuthorName<br>";
print "$BookContent<br><br>";

$rs->Close;

?>
```

Comment: where is the selected Author ?

Comment: I added that in! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: VR46 fixed syntax error for sql, did my suggettion fix the rest ?

Comment: No, it did not. Is it odd that once I updated the
author=$authorid; to     '$authorid' I now get variables undefined for the Book, Author & BookContent?

Comment: That would mean your query didn't get any results. The variables you've mentioned only get their respective values if the query had results. The `if (!$rs->EOF)` should have an `else` clause that sets the variables to a blank string (or anything else you'd want). That's one way of doing it. Another way of doing it is assigning values to those variables before your `if` statement, so that they still have values whether or not `!$rs->EOF` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. There should be a match within the database though. It sounds like I am not properly taking the users selection to pull the proper content in this case. I will try adjusting per your suggestions as well.

Comment: @Revenant  My goodness, I found the issue! My user query was actually "authorid" not "author". It was so silly of me.